# iPhone simulator not visible in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator, simulator

I recently updated my Xcode from 9.2 to 9.3. But unfortunately, all iPhone simulators are no longer visible.

[image: screen shot]

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Make sure other xcode are not opening.

Comment: I completely closed and opened Xcode again...

Comment: Yes, I got when I restart my system completely...

Comment: In my case, my system version does not support some iOS versions. To check this just run this command (xcrun simctl list runtimes) in terminal. When I run this I got these results: iOS 9.3 (9.3 - 13E233) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-3 (unavailable, The iOS 9.3 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 10.14.99.) iOS 10.0 (10.0 - 14A345) - (unavailable, The iOS 10.0 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 10.14.99.) iOS 10.3 (10.3.1 - 14E8301) - (unavailable, The iOS 10.3 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 10.15.99.)

Answer (score 5):

**You have to delete Derived Data.**

In Xcode, go to `Preferences` > `Locations` > `Derived Data` : click the little arrow to open the derived data path in Finder. Delete the `DerivedData` folder.

Restart Xcode.

It should work.

Comment: Thank you. I restored my Mac completely, now I got all simulators. Thank you very much...

Comment: Oh, hard way !  Glad to know your problem is solved. Should have work by just deleting `Derived Data` :)

Answer (score 3):

All way above not working for me. It's took for 3 days, finally I found exactly way to fix this error. Because `iOS Deployment Target` under build settings is higher than list simulator. I was using Xcode 12 while the deployment target was set to iOS 14.5. I got the list of simulators as soon as I set it to iOS 14.4. So you just need to downgrade IOS version smaller than IOS version in simulator.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also remember to check the **architectures**, they must match the type of device, for example, if you only have **arm64** selected nothing will appear, **you must select armv7, or both.**

Answer (score 1):

Also you have two options as shown in your screenshot.

1. Add additional simulators
2. Download simulators

Try them out

Answer (score 1):

I have another solution, You can also perform these steps, to resolve this problem:

Step 1: Select Preferences... from menu

[image: Step 1]

Step 2: Select locations from top tab

[image: Step 2:]

Step 3: select xcode which you use.

[image: Step 3: select xcode which you use.]

If Simulator doesn't show after this process then Quit XCode and then reopen again.

Answer (score 1):

Lowering down the deployment target in the build settings did the trick for me.